# How do I resolve obtaining the dashboard features created with CPT UI in localhost onto my live site?

Tags: custom-post-types

I utilized a great plugin during development called Custom Post Types UI by WebDevStudios. Its an Admin UI for creating post types and custom taxonomies for WordPress dashboard. The problem is the custom post types I created on localhost did not all populate when I added this plugin to the production site. How do I resolve this short of redoing all the custom post types on the live site again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you migrated your database to the server already?

Comment: No, I created a new database. I think you just answered my question.

Comment: For the migration you can do it manually, but you'll need to rename your localhost paths to fit the server paths. I'd recommend using this plugin if you're not comfortable with SQL. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/